# PDF Invoice changes working fine on local system but issue with server side

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, magento1.9.3.1

I have made customization in PDF invoice files.

Case 1) 
Copied files from below

```
app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf
```

Files Copied: **Abstract.php, Invoice.php, Shipment.php, Creditmemo.php**

Created Structure like below, pasted here and customize the changes.

```
app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf
```

Case 2) 
Copied files from below

```
app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items
```

Files Copied: **Abstract.php**

Created Structure like below, pasted here and customize the changes.

```
app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items
```

Case 3) 
PDF invoice was having issue in printing **Rs Symbol**. So i have downloaded dejavu-sans and after making changes in above files. its working fine in local system.

**But when i uploaded the same changes on server side. Nothing seems to work.
Is there any thing different needs to be done on server side?**

Comment: Flush the cache maybe ?

Comment: Did it 4 times. but did not seem to work.